# UUOC with ssh file transfer

Tags: ssh, cat

Just wondering; is it possible to skip the `cat` in

```
some_command | ssh remote 'cat > outputfile'
```

? It feels like a [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: It is a UUOC (useful use of cat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need something that reads its stdin and writes it to some file. `cat` is a good choice for that as it supports binary data and doesn't do anything fancy with its input so is small and efficient.

You could do:

```
... | ssh remote 'cp /dev/stdin outputfile`
```

But that would not be more efficient and would only work on systems that have `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: Using `cp /dev/stdin` solves my problem, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712933/does-unix-have-a-command-to-read-from-stdin-and-write-to-a-file-like-tee-withou.  Where I wanted to use `sudo cp /dev/stdin /etc/root-access-file`.  Thanks!
Feel free to answer that question with information. :-)