# Does Unix have a command to read from stdin and write to a file (like tee without sending output to stdout)?

Tags: file-copy

I want to copy files that require root to read/write from one system to another.
My current solution is to use sudo on each system and use tee as shown.

```
ssh host sudo cat /etc/somefile | sudo tee /etc/somefile > /dev/null
```

This works but tee sends it's input to stdout so I have to send `tee`'s ouput to /dev/null.

I looked to the UNIX `cat` and copy command `cp` and did not find an answer.
See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html
and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html

---

UPDATED:  I now realize that I should have stated that the solution needs to support `sudo` so the simple solution of using `cat` won't work.

For example,

```
ssh host sudo cat /etc/somefile | sudo cat > /etc/somefile
```

fails because the directory `/etc` can only be written by root (in my case) and the re-direction to the file `> /etc/somefile` runs under the current user (who doesn't have access to write to /etc).

Comment: Related: [UUOC with ssh file transfer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/76569)

Comment: Related: [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's:

```
sh -c 'exec cat > file'
```

Or for arbitrary `$file`s, passed either as environment variables:

```
sudo FILE="$file" sh -c 'exec cat > "$FILE"'
```

Or as argument:

```
sudo sh -c 'exec cat > "$1"' sh "$file"
```

(where `sh` goes into `$0`, and the contents of `$file` in `$1` for that inline script).

(see also `>>` in place of `>` to open in *append* mode, or `1<>` to open without truncation (and in read+write mode) to overwrite the file in place, similar to `dd`'s `conv=notrunc`).

In any case, do **not** do:

```
sudo sh -c "exec cat > $file"
```

As that fails if `$file` contains any character special in the shell syntax such as space, `;`, `$`... and introduces a command injection vulnerability.

---

There's also:

```
dd bs=65536 of=file
```

(with `status=none` with the GNU implementation of `dd` or compatible to suppress the transfer report. There are more options to control how the file is opened, the list of which varies with the `dd` implementation).

---

On most systems:

```
cp /dev/stdin file
```

---

There's also `moreutils`'s

```
sponge file
```

---

With GNU `sort` at least and on text input:

```
sort -mo file
```

---

With text input (or `sed` implementations that can cope with non-text):

```
sed -n 'w file'
```

---

With text input:

```
awk '{print > "file"}'
```

Or with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v ORS= '{print $0 RT > "file"}'
```

---

Here, you could also open the local file as root and then run `ssh` as the regular user:

```
sudo zsh -c '
  USERNAME=$SUDO_USER ssh host 'sudo cat /etc/somefile' > /etc/somefile'
```

That means the data doesn't have to be shoved through an extra pipe.

You could also compress on the fly with `xz` and decompress on the local end with `pixz` which supports uncompressing into a file:

```
ssh host 'sudo xz -0 -c /etc/somefile' | sudo pixz -tdo /etc/somefile
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen you give a answer using `dd` when either `cp` or `cat` would work instead. Is there an equivalent to the useless use of dd?

Comment: @doneal24, `cat` alone can't do it here, you need it combined with `sh` to open the file for writing. `dd` can do the opening and read+write loop, `cp` as well, though `/dev/stdin` is not fully portable.

Comment: `dd iflag=fullblock`

Comment: @roaima,  that's GNU specific and not necessary without a `count`, `dd` just transfers along what it reads, short read or not.

Comment: Is GNU particularly less reliable than any other? You _need_ `iflag=fullblock` when reading variable sized blocks (or maybe just temporarily zero byte blocks) with GNU `dd`

Comment: @roaima You need iflag=fullblock in `cmd | dd bs=somesize count=1 iflag=fullblock of=file` if you want to make sure `file` contains the first somesize bytes of the output of `cmd`. You don't need it if you omit `count` to get the full output of `cmd` into `file`.

Comment: @PatS, try `sh -c 'echo "scriptname: $0; 1st arg: $1, 2nd: $2"; will-error-out' A B C D` to demonstrate how you pass arguments to an inline script (a script whose contents is passed as the `-c` argument).

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple files and they need to be in the same places on the destination, `tar` can copy files, here to a different directory, but the pipe could also involve `ssh` somehow. Flavor with `p` to preserve file permissions or maybe some compression flags if `ssh` isn't doing that for you.

```
$ mkdir output
$ echo foo > foo
$ echo bar > bar
$ tar cf - foo bar | ( cd output && tar xf - )
$ cat output/*
bar
foo
```

There may be portability problems if the implementation of `tar` differs between the systems.

Answer (score -1):

`cat` is the simplest program that does as you ask.  Especially `cat -`, which tells the command to read data from its standard input.

The left-hand side of your pipe command is unclear about what `sudo` does with `/etc/somefile`.  Here's my best guess at the answer:

```
sudo cat /etc/somefile | ssh me@otherhost 'sudo cat - > /etc/somefile'
```

Comment: This would require that the shell be running as root, which I don't think is the case for OP. It's for that reason that you can't do something like `sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/some/sysctl/file` either.

Comment: @forest yes, thank you.  I missed that aspect of the question.  Edited my answer.

Comment: In `ssh me@otherhost 'sudo cat - > /etc/somefile'`, `/etc/somefile` is still opened by `me`, not `root` on host. You'd need `ssh me@otherhost 'exec sudo sh -c "exec cat > /etc/somefile"'` to run a shell as root that opens the file for writing.

Comment: @SottoVoce, I downvoted because the answer as it is written doesn't work.  If you incorporate Stephane Chazelas comment, the answer is acceptable and I'll remove the downvote.